# Can't Import Any Code Samples With Android Studio 3.1.4

Tags: android-studio, connectivity

I am trying to simply open a code sample with Android Studio as follows:

[image]

But when I click on "Import an Android code sample," this happens:

[image]

I am testing this problem and writing this question right now, so if you're reading this, then that is proof that I'm online, so please don't suggest any connection testing, modem resetting, etc.

I have already tried:

- Verifying I am online
- Resetting my modem, router, etc.
- Restarting computer (Macbook)
- Restarting Android Studio
- Selecting "open code sample" from different menus.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem right now... or had any past experience with it?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been raised as a Google Issue here and is now resolved on the backend:

[Android studio 3.1.4 - failed to download samples index (when trying to download google code samples)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52365535/android-studio-3-1-4-failed-to-download-samples-index-when-trying-to-download/52374802#52374802)

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115837589