# Android studio 3.1.4 - failed to download samples index (when trying to download google code samples)

Tags: android-studio

I have tried both on a windows 10 machine and Ubuntu (18.04) with the latest release of Android studio I am unable to download Google Code Samples.

the error states 'Failed to download samples index, please check your connection and try again'.

the fix suggested for an earlier instance of this issue from 2015 to change proxy settings from 'no proxy' to 'auto detected' doesn't seem to work with the latest (3.1.4) release of Android Studio.

**Update**: 
Apparently this  is an active issue at the backend and currently WIP
Please check below link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/115837589

FWIW, I'm based in Australia.

Comment: FWIW, I am also based in Australia, having same issue with same version of Android Studio (3.1.4) on Windows x64 Professional.
The recommended fix (File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior->System Settings->HTTP Proxy : Auto-detect proxy settings) 
also does not work for me.

Comment: For now, I'll rely on the github source (these have only been updated for AS v3.1.3):

[https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master)

Comment: Same issue, UK based, Ubuntu 18.04, Android Studio 3.1.4

Comment: I've updated the original question with the status from issue tracker. I had raised this as a bit for Android studoo

Comment: super thanks for this questions. The issue has been resolved now.